# Access C# class from another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I'm learning C#...

I use **visual studio**.
I created a 2 classes (person & work) using Project>Add class.
Now I have 3 files for main, person & work.

I want to access "person" class from withing the work class in the work file but I am missing something here.

While I have no problem accessing "Person" from withing main, in work, I can define it but not access it, that is not set values to it neither access its method.

My headers look like this:

```
using System;

namespace myTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

============= Person ====================

```
using System;

namespace myTest
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name;

        public void say_name()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is ", Name);
        }
    }
}
```

============= Work =================

```
using System;

namespace myTest
{
    public class Work
    {
        Person Bob = new Person();
        Bob.Name = "Bob";             //<=  This will not work
        Bob.say_name();                 //<=  This will not work
    }
}
```

Comment: You put code directly into the class. Code must be in functions, with the exclusion of some initializers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code logic have to be placed inside methods.
Something like this:

```
namespace myTest
{
    public class Work
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Person Bob = new Person();
            Bob.Name = "Bob";           
            Bob.say_name();              
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Work
{
    public Person Bob = new Person();

    public Work()
    {
        Bob.Name = "Bob";
        Bob.say_name();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Work myWork = new Work();
    myWork.Bob.say_name();
}
```